# how do I install cmislib for Python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, cmis

Im trying to install the latest cmislib for python 3 (I have pydev installed) using easy_install (which Ive never used before) as described in

http: //chemistry.apache.org/python/docs/install.html#requirements

I get the following error, so either Im doing something obviously silly or this doesnt work with python 3.3 ?

C:\Users\myStuff\Downloads>c:\python33\scripts\easy_install-3.3 cmslib-0.5.1-py2.7

Searching for cmslib-0.5.1-py2.7
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cmslib-0.5.1-py2.7/
Couldn't find index page for 'cmslib-0.5.1-py2.7' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for cmslib-0.5.1-py2.7
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cmslib-0.5.1-py2.7')

Any suggestions ? Is there a different way to install cmislib?

thx

Answer (score 1):

I have never tested cmislib with Python 3.x but the differences between Python 2.x and 3.x are significant, so I am not at all surprised that it does not work.

Please try it with Python 2.7. Using easy_install as described is the best way to do it.

Comment: thanks Jeff, I thought that may be the case. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score -1):

you must update directly the python code of the cmislib-0.5.1-py3.4.egg package , from python 2.7 to python 3.4

Comment: Without any detailed instructions or links to how to do this, this answer isn't very helpful